# Connecting multiple monitors to single display port

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, vga, dvi

I just purchased Lenovo Thinkpad S430 i have two external ports:
1x Mini HDMI
1x Mini DisplayPort (Thunderbolt)

GPU: Intel HD 4000 with Nvidia 620M Optimus GPU. I purchased this notebook soley for the
MiniDisplay port's capability to output to multiple screens.

However I'm not fully sure how to go about this and I have one concern.
My previous Notebook had a HDMI and VGA ports and ATI 6770M HD but was able to output only to one extra screen so I could only have one extra monitor connected.

I have two monitors one can be connected via HDMI/VGA/DVI/USB and one can be connected via
VGA or DVI.

Now I want to use all 3 screens my laptops and have my desktop extended to both external screens. What do I need to connect two screens to one DP ?

I found this but I'm not sure what i should be looking for:
http://dx.com/p/3-in-1-mini-displayport-male-to-hdmi-displayport-dvi-female-adapter-37374

and this:

http://www.logilink.eu/showproduct/CV0045.htm?seticlanguage=en

I have Intel i5 DualCore IvyBridge CPU (3rd generation) which Intel claims can support up to 3 monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try connecting your 2 monitors to the both ports on your notebook first - mini HDMI port to the HDMI connector on the 1st monitor and mini DP port via miniDP-to-DVI adapter(or cable) to the DVI connector on your 2nd monitor.

The Logilink CV0045 adapter only supports 1 connection at a time - you won't be able to connect multiple monitors to the single DP using it.

DisplayPort standard supports connecting multiple monitors to the same port - you need to buy MST (multi-stream transport) hub or a Monitor with the hub already built-in.

Comment: I tried searching for MST Hub but found nothing how are these usually called ?

Comment: There are not that many of them available on the market. Check this Club3D CSV-5300 http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/mst-hub-1-3.html